# change the order of tableviewcells with animation

Tags: iphone, animation, uitableview

Is there a way to change the order of tableviewcells with animation?
I want to slide up or down cells and change the ordering.
But i dont know if it is possible with animation?
I need help.
Thanks,Tintin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that `UITableView's` edit mode.

[Iphone sdk tutorial Add/Delete/Reorder UITableView row.](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/)

Answer (score 0):

In this code dataArray is the name of my array  you change it with your own array name

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return YES;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

    NSString *stringToMove = [[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row] retain];
    [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.dataArray insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    [stringToMove release];
    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: if u dont mind you should accept answer if you have got it and if you like an answer which had help you ,you can vote up also.